# NodeJS and TCP performance

Tags: node.js, tcp

I'm testing communication between two NodeJS instances over TCP, using the [**net** module](http://nodejs.org/api/net.html).

Since the TCP doesn't rely on messages (`socket.write()`), I'm wrapping each message in a string like `msg "{ json: 'encoded' }";` in order to handle them individually (otherwise, I'd receive packets with a random number of concatenated messages).

I'm running two NodeJS instances (server and client) on a CentOS 6.5 VirtualBox VM with bridged network and a Core i3-based host machine. The test lies on the client emitting a request to the server and waiting for the response:

1. Client connects to the server.
2. Client outputs current timestamp (`Date.now()`).
3. Client emits *n* requests.
4. Server replies to *n* requests.
5. Client increments a counter on every response.
6. When finished, client outputs the current timestamp.

The code is quite simple:

**Server**

```
var net = require('net');

var server = net.createServer(function(socket) {

    socket.setNoDelay(true);

    socket.on('data', function(packet) {

        // Split packet in messages.
        var messages = packet.toString('utf-8').match(/msg "[^"]+";/gm);

        for (var i in messages) {

            // Get message content (msg "{ content: 'json' }";). Actually useless for the test.
            //var message = messages[i].match(/"(.*)"/)[1];

            // Emit response:
            socket.write('msg "PONG";');

        }

    });

});

server.listen(9999);
```

**Client**

```
var net = require('net');

var WSClient = new net.Socket();

WSClient.setNoDelay(true);

WSClient.connect(9999, 'localhost', function() {

    var req = 0;
    var res = 0;

    console.log('Start:', Date.now());

    WSClient.on('data', function(packet) {

        var messages = packet.toString("utf-8").match(/msg "[^"]+";/gm);

        for (var i in messages) {

            // Get message content (msg "{ content: 'json' }";). Actually useless for the test.
            //var message = messages[i].match(/"(.*)"/)[1];

            res++;
            if (res === 1000) console.log('End:', Date.now());

        }

    });

    // Emit requests:
    for (req = 0; req <= 1000; req++) WSClient.write('msg "PING";');

});
```

My results are:

- With 1 request: 9 - 24 ms
- With 1000 requests: 478 - 512 ms
- With 10000 requests: 5021 - 5246 ms

My pings (ICMP) to localhost are between 0.6 - 0.1 seconds. I've not intense network traffic or CPU usage (running SSH, FTP, Apache, Memcached, and Redis).

**Is this normal** for NodeJS and TCP or it is just my CentOS VM or my low-performance host? Should I move to another platform like Java or a native C/C++ server?

I think that a 15 ms delay (average) per request on localhost is not acceptable for my project.

Comment: I would recommend not to use `setNoDelay` and have a decent parser for messages (because for larger messages it will fail), also try streams V2 interface. If you want even more performance try working with the cluster module.

Comment: another thing 1k requests in 500ms and 10k in 5 seconds it's a quite good result, it is about 2 request / ms which is 0.5 ms delay for request or isn't it?

Comment: @Oriol Are you able to get the better peroformance or not ?

Comment: @Vicb No, I couldn't. I guess these are "normal" results.

Comment: I had also done the same test on my mac and ec2 c3.xl it gives me the same result. If you found any thing please update the thread tahnks.

Answer (score 5):

Wrapping the messages in some text and searching for a Regex match isn't enough.

The `net.Server` and `net.Socket` interfaces have a raw TCP stream as an underlying data source. The `data` event will fire whenever the underlying TCP stream has data available.

The problem is, you don't control the TCP stack. The timing of it firing `data` events has nothing to do with the logic of your code. So you have no guarantee that the `data` event that drives your listeners has exactly one, less than one, more than one, or any number and some remainder, of messages being sent. In fact, you can pretty much guarantee that the underlying TCP stack WILL break up your data into chunks. And the listener only fires when a chunk is available. Your current code has no shared state between `data` events.

You only mention latency, but I expect if you check, you will also find that the count of messages received (on both ends) is not what you expect. That's because any partial messages that make it across will be lost completely. If the TCP stream sends half a message at the end of chunk 1, and the remainder in chunk 2, the split message will be totally dropped.

The easy and robust way is to use a messaging protocol like ØMQ. You will need to use it on both endpoints. It takes care of framing the TCP stream into atomic messages.

If for some reason you will connecting to or receiving traffic from external sources, they will probably use something like a length header. Then what you want to do is create a Transform stream that buffers incoming traffic, and only emits data when the amount identified in the header has arrived.

Answer (score 1):

Have you done any network dump? You may be creating network congestion due to the overhead introduced by enabling 'no delay' socket property. This property will send data down to TCP stack as soon as possible and if you have very small chunks of information it will lead to many TCP packets with small payloads, thus the decreasing transmission efficiency and eventually having TCP pausing the transmission due to congestion. If u want to use 'no delay' for your sockets, try increasing your receiving socket buffer so that data is pulled from the tcp stack faster. Let us know if that helped.